# Вывести информацию в уже созданную строку listView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Столкнулся с проблемой: Как вывести что-либо в уже созданный item в listView? 
Коротко о ситуации - есть listView, в нем есть 4 столбца, в цикле в первые 3 столбца выводится информация. Как теперь записать в первую строку в 4ый столбец?

```
            listView1.Columns.Add("r", 30, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Xr" + iter.ToString(), 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("L1", 40, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
            listView1.Columns.Add("Er" + iter.ToString(), 40, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            ...

            for (int i = 0; i < iL1.Length; i++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add("1").SubItems.Add(Xr[i].ToString());
                listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(iL1[i].ToString());
            }

            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(<выводимая_информация>);
```

где `i` - номер столбца